# Don't show the "How does SE work" banner to users who have accounts on other sites

Tags: feature-request, login, auto-login

When visiting a site where a user doesn't have an account, the "How does SE work" <sup>1</sup> banner doesn't really need to be shown to users who have accounts on other sites. If you've been on the network for any length of time then you should really know how SE works.

The system knows you have other accounts because it shows the "join this community" <sup>2</sup> link rather than "sign up" and "log in" links, so it's not as if that information isn't available to the page.

[image: what you see if you have accounts elsewhere]

It may be worth displaying the message if the user has fewer than (say) 5 accounts and the oldest account is less than (say) a month old as they probably are a new user and perhaps do need reminding of how the system works.

A more reliable metric might be that the days visited count is greater than (say) 30 or that they'd get the association bonus were they to create an account. Either way, it's an indication that the user knows what they're about.

Comment: an option to consider instead of criteria for "oldest account is less than..." etc is "days visited at one of the accounts is over <pick a sensible number>". Days visited looks like more reliable metric; old accounts may still be 1-day visitor

Comment: @gnat Good point. I'll update.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with your proposal (+1).

However as they may or may not know how the site *they're viewing* works specifically, instead of just *removing* the "How Stack works" paragraph, what about:

1. Show the "How Stack Exchange works" paragraph (current one) when
   user is deemed "new user to Stack Exchange" (whatever criteria is
   decided upon)
2. Show the  top paragraph from that site's Tour page when the user is
   not (1) but new to that site. And possibly under the paragraph links
   to the Help Center "what is on topic here" and "what should I avoid
   asking"
3. Show nothing when user neither (1) or (2) - not new to Stack or that
   site

The first paragraph on each site's Tour page is a useful snippet which gives a brief idea of what the site is about, and I have often found the top paragraph from the Tour page description enough so I know what the site allows.

### Advantages

This improves that content area usage greatly because:

1. New users get taught how to use Stack Exchange in general
2. Users familiar with Stack Exchange get useful info/intro to a
   specific site they're not familiar with, and prompted to the
   important Help Center parts
3. Users familiar with both Stack and the site they're on get the
   *privilege* of having no text  there and so (regular users) get more
   questions on the screen without scrolling

Comment: Hmm. I would hope that someone familiar with the network would take the Tour anyway to do just that, but I fear that my hope is misplaced.

Comment: @ChrisF So if they are new to that site and taking the Tour would be helpful, why not show them the bit of the Tour which is relevant to that site? The rest of the Tour under the top paragraph is essentially showing "How Stack Exchange works", not that site specifically. And if they're seeing the Tour paragraph instead we've already decided they don't need to know "How Stack works in general". Without my *additional* idea, you are just removing all help, their going to the Tour or not isn't likely changed by my idea, or yours. In fact, my idea brings it to them.

Comment: @ChrisF judging by myself, your hope is _definitely_ misplaced

Comment: This is a good answer.